# element.find does not work for nested elements inside ng-switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that contains an `ng-switch` DOM element. I need to bind an event to a DOM node under the ng-switch, but for some reason element.find does not return any nodes under the switch element!

In the example below, I expect `element.find("*")` to return ng-switch, one div and the button yet it only returns ng-switch and the button.

How can I solve this? Or reach DOM nodes under ng-switch from the link function a different way?

**Code to reproduce:**

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
    <div my-directive>
        <ng-switch on="selection">
            <div ng-switch-when="A" class="a">A</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="B" class="b">B</div>
            <div ng-switch-default>default</div>
        </ng-switch>        
        <button ng-click="switchSelection()" >switch</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element.find("*"));
            console.log("Didn't find my divs :(");
        }
    }
});


function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selection="B";

    $scope.switchSelection=function(){
        if ($scope.selection=="B"){
            $scope.selection="A";
        }
        else{
            $scope.selection="B";
        }
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/KCPVZ/)

Comment: `ng-switch` will only place applicable elements in the DOM, not all of them. Inspect the live html in browser console, will see only one DIV. WHat are you trying to do?

Comment: Still, this means that find() would return ONE div which it doesn't.

Comment: when using DOM manipulation on angular created elements, best to wrap  DOM search code in `$timeout`. http://jsfiddle.net/KCPVZ/3/. Even when duration is zero it gives digest cycle chance to finish

Comment: Is direct DOM manipulation really necessary to what you're trying to do? Angular typically provides an easier way.

Comment: @Rosarch The ultimate goal is to bind the load event of some images in my directive under my `ng-switch`. How else would you reach the image elements and bind the 'load' event from the link function?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question in the comment asking how to bind a load event to the image if it's within a switch.

What you can do is create a directive for the images and then bind the load event within the linking function

```
.directive("myImageDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element){
            element.bind("load", function(){
                console.log("element loaded");
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kB4vq/

The scope.$apply(); is to let angular know to re-process itself if you need it too, since the load happens outside of angular's knowledge. You can read up more on that here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but this does not exactly answer my question regarding reaching elements inside an `ng-switch`. I have several images and I need to perform these 'load' binds relative to some logic in the parent directive, so adding directives to the images does not help in that case.

Comment: You can access the parents scope via scope.$parent if you like. So in the load element you could do something like scope.$parent.whatDoIDo(). As for searching through, no you can't do that without the timeout method. The problem is the elements haven't been created by that point.

Comment: I was under the impression directives are created from the bottom up - so in that case the `ng-switch` would get created and be available in my directive's link function. Is that not the case here?

Comment: It is available, the problem is it's not created yet. Javascript and the dom manipulations (putting the elements in via ng-switch) are happening at different times. The javascript is happening first which is why you can't find the elements. The dom insertion is coming afterwards. This is why $timeout would be the way to do what you want. Regardless the general principle of angular is to not do dom searching. Using the directive methodology I described above along with scope.$parent should cover your case. If it's not I can help figure out what you want to do. If possible create a jsfiddle.